# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'function' and 'int'

Tags: python

I don't know why i can x**2 and y**2
please help i need this i dont get why im
getting this error...
.
.
.
.
..
.
.
..
..
.
.
.
.
.

```
def regresion(lista,n):
a=0
b=0
if isinstance(n,int):
    a =((x**2)(y**2)-n(promx)(promy)) / (((x**2)**2)-n(promx**2))

    b =(promy-(n)(promx**2))
else:
    "n no es entero"
return a,b

def x(lista):
a=[]
c=0
x=0
if lista!=[]:
    for i in lista:
        c = i[0]
        a = a + [c]
    for i in a:
        x = x + i

    return x
def y(lista):
b=[]
d=0
y=0
if lista!=[]:
    for i in lista:
            d = i[1]
            b = b + [d]

    for i in b:
            y = y + i

    return y
def promx(lista):
a=[]
c=0
x=0
promx=0
if lista!=[]:
    for i in lista:
        c = i[0]
        a = a + [c]

    for i in a:
        x = x + i
    promx= x / len(a)

    return promx
def promy(lista):
b=[]
d=0
y=0
promy=0
if lista!=[]:
    for i in lista:
            d = i[1]
            b = b + [d]

    for i in b:
            y = y + i
    promy= y / len(b)
return promy
```

Comment: Instead of `if something != []`, just do `if not something`.  It's more robust.

Comment: Python doesn't support multiplying `x**2` and `y**2` by just writing `(x**2)(y**2)`. In math, the notation `f(x)` is actually ambiguous; it looks like a function application, but it could also be multiplying a number `f` by a number `x`. Python can't allow that ambiguity, so multiplication always requires you to actually use the multiplication operator, `*`.

Comment: Howi can actually do that?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is intented terribly and has too many dots, but I think this is the issue.

On this line:

```
a =((x**2)(y**2)-n(promx)(promy)) / (((x**2)**2)-n(promx**2))
```

You call:

```
promx**2
```

Which is raising `promx` to the power `2` using exponentiation.

However, `promx` is a function, so by calling `promx**2` you are saying raise this function definition to the power 2. Which doesn't make sense. What you need to do is *call* `promx` with a value like so:

```
promx(X)**2
```

Where X is a list that fills the argument the function `promx` requires.

Comment: Calling it and power it to 2 what i really need is that the result from the function is getting power 2

Comment: @user2771090 Yeah, well, you need to modify the code to call your function. What you have won't work for the reason stated in your title. You can't square a function definition.

Comment: @user2771090 I've told you how to call it. I think you need to review how Python works and how functions are defined and used.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been useful :)

Comment: @user2771090 If the answer solves your question you can let other users know by accepting the answer, and if it was useful you can upvote it to acknowledge that too.