# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'list' and 'list'

Tags: python

Why i get this error what i need is to move the even numbers to the second list in order by size and later from the second list to the first the odd numbers in order by size too.. i'm a noob in this please help me understand

```
def listas_par_impar(lista,lista2):
    for i in lista2:
        if (i%10)%2==0:
          lista=lista+[i]
          lista2-=[i]
        else:
            pass

    return lista, lista2
```

Comment: Why would you first want to add `i` to the list and then immediately remove it?

Comment: oh that was a mistake that is lista2-=[i]

Comment: Why do you want to remove it from lista2? And modifying lista2 while you are iterating over it is a bad idea for obvious reasons.

Comment: `(i%10)%2` is mathematically equivalent to `i%2`.  Also, testing against 0 isn't terribly Pythonic versus just saying `not i%2`.  `if` statements don't need an `else` either (`else: pass` is clutter)

Comment: is because lista2 if for odd number no even

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what i need is to move the even numbers to the second list in order by
>   size

First, sort the list, and then build your new list with the even numbers. In this example, `i` is `[10,6,5,4,7,8,9,1,3,2]`:

```
i.sort() # sorting the list
even = [] # will store the even numbers

for key,value in enumerate(i):
   if not value % 2:
       # if the number is even,
       # remove it from i and add it to
       # the even list
       even.append(i.pop(key))
```

Here is an example of the above using a list comprehension, which is a short hand way to write loops that return lists:

```
>>> i = [10,6,5,4,7,8,9,1,3,2]
>>> i.sort()
>>> even = [i.pop(k) for k,v in enumerate(i) if not v % 2]
>>> even
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> i
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

To move them to another list, just add the two lists together:

```
>>> another_list
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> another_list + even
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Then, you do the same thing, sort the `another_list`, and then create a new list with only odd numbers, and add it to the original list.

Answer (score 2):

`lista -= [i]` translates to `lista = lista - [i]`.  You can't subtract from a list (you can add however—and do—which concatenates the two iterables together).

If you want to remove an element, you can `lista.pop()` it off or slice it: `lista = lista[:-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't subtract a list from a list.

`x -= y` is short hand for `x = x - y`. While the `+` operator does work for lists, the `-` does not.

[You appear to have trouble with error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755086/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-or-pow-function-and-int/18755140?noredirect=1#comment27646817_18755140), and in future I'd suggest googling them first and trying alternate solutions before asking StackOverflow.